# Grouping files in the same directory based on the content

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, grouping

I have a question regarding grouping files that have the same content, but different file names. I looked into `filecmp.cmp()`, but that only compares two files at a time.

The idea is to turn something like this:

```
file1: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
file2: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
file3: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
file4: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
file5: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
file6: [a,b,c,d,e]
```

Into:

```
file(1,2,3): [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
file(4,5): [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
file(6): [a,b,c,d,e]
```

I think I have about 1800 .txt files, but only about 20 unique files. I want to create a list, or a dictionary, or a data frame that shows the grouping.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your help. Sorry, I just realized I never actually responded to your answers and suggestions. I ended up using the dictionary method suggested by Abe Binder. Again, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic way would be to use dictionaries. First Complie a list of all the file names in the directory and store it to a list named file_names. Then:

```
filedict={}
for name in file_names:
    file=open(name,"r")
    filecontents=file.read()
    if filecontents in filedict:
        filedict[filecontents].append(name)
    else:
        filedict[filecontents]=[]
        filedict[filecontents].append(name)
```

Each values of this dictionary will be a list of files with the same text contents. The keys of the dictionary will be the string of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash function like SHA-1 to check files with the same content, here is an extract from this [source](https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-files-with-python/):

```
import hashlib
BLOCKSIZE = 65536

def hash_value_for(file_name):
  hasher = hashlib.sha1()
  with open(file_name, 'rb') as afile:
      buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
      while len(buf) > 0:
          hasher.update(buf)
          buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)

  return hasher.hexdigest()
```

For example, the above function, given a file name will return back the hash value of its content.

**file1.txt**

> This is a test.

**file2.txt**

> This is a test!

**file3.txt**

> This is a test.

**Output:**

```
print(hash_value_for("file1.txt"))
> 0828324174b10cc867b7255a84a8155cf89e1b8b
print(hash_value_for("file2.txt"))
> cc4bc53ee478380f385721b45247107338a9cec3
print(hash_value_for("file3.txt"))
> 0828324174b10cc867b7255a84a8155cf89e1b8b
```

Now back to your original example:

**Files:**

Assuming that we have the following files with the following content for each:

```
file1: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
file2: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
file3: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
file4: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
file5: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
file6: [a,b,c,d,e]
```

**Code:**

```
import hashlib
import itertools

BLOCKSIZE = 65536


def hash_value_for(file_name):
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as afile:
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)

    return hasher.hexdigest()


file_names = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt",
              "file4.txt", "file5.txt", "file6.txt"]

file_names_with_hash_values = {}
for file_name in file_names:
    file_names_with_hash_values[file_name] = hash_value_for(file_name)

result = {}
for key, value in sorted(file_names_with_hash_values.items()):
    result.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'e99a894b164a9274e7dabc1b77b41f4148860d96': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'], 
'bf141159c6499f26f46c7bdc28914417ff66aa15': ['file4.txt', 'file5.txt'], 
'a019bdc760a550cdc55de1343d4ebbcff1ba49c3': ['file6.txt']}
```

This is just an example, you can change the code to suit your needs (and get the desired output).